# Input validation ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, validation

I want to try validating my input. On ReactJS component (not container)

```html
<form id="aform" onSubmit={this.props.submit} className={classes}>
 <label> Name: 
  <input name="name" type="text" onChange={this.props.changed} value={this.props.value} defaultValue={this.props.slug}/>
 </label>
  <label>
  Description:
  <input typ="text" name="description" onChange={this.props.changed} value={this.props.value} defaultValue={this.props.description}/>
 </label>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.cancelCourse}/>
</form>
```

In the above code snippet, I am making a form with a submit. I want to disable the submit button depending on the length of the name input. I can't find a good way where the reference is within the component. So the goal is to validate only within the component, using an if else statement that references to the input name.

Comment: `<input type="submit" disabled={this.props.value.length < 5} .../>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `disabled` prop:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" disabled={this.props.value.length < 10} onClick={this.cancelCourse}  />
```